# Special characters from xml file don't display correctly using php

Tags: php, character, echo

This may be a stupid question but its not a matter of what I can find, its a matter that I dont know what to search for. There are some special characters that don't show correctly in php. I'm taking some information from an xml file, and echo-ing them.

ie:

should be -> Nürnberg

echoes as -> NÃ¼rnberg

any tips on what to look for, or how to resolve this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8"  />
```

Comment: yeap, thanx. look at my comment on deceze's answer.

Answer (score 1):

You simply have an *encoding mismatch*. Get up to speed with these articles:

[What Every Programmer Absolutely, Positively Needs To Know About Encodings And Character Sets To Work With Text](http://kunststube.net/encoding/)
[Handling Unicode Front To Back In A Web App](http://kunststube.net/frontback/)

Comment: It was a matter of utf-8 meta tag. However here's something strange that someone should know, or attempt to find.

I have a list of these items, lets call it store. I also have a virtual shopping cart, we'll call it cart.

The store gets its info at page load from database/xml, and outputs html. The cart gets this same exact info from database/xml, but through ajax, not on page load, and outputs it. Store does not output correct characters, while cart does. None of them had any charset declared. How is this explained?

Answer (score 0):

try a different character set on the page you're echoing from

http://www.w3schools.com/tags/ref_charactersets.asp

Comment: Make sure, everything is in the same charset: Your html, forms, database, files... Open your XML file in an editor that is capable to save it in a different format, like UTF-8.

Answer (score 0):

Can you try with following meta tag in your HTML head.

```
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=ISO-8859-1"  />
```

Answer (score 0):

"I'm taking some information from an xml file, and echo-ing them."

Windows command line doesn't support utf8 properly as it doesn't use an UTF8 font.

Just put the file into somewhere that's reachable through a web server and test it by calling the file through the web server.
Alternatively pipe the output of the script into a text file:

php test.php > output.txt

And either open output.txt is a UTF8 capable editor or use a utf8 capable 'Tail' program.

Test.php

```
<?php
    echo "Nürnberg";
?>
```

Running from command prompt:

```
php test.php

∩╗┐N├╝rnberg
```

Calling through a web server http://localhost/test.php

```
Nürnberg
```

Comment: That's not a *font* issue, it's an *encoding* issue. Also, why are you mentioning the Windows command line specifically?

Comment: Because every 6 months I forget that PHP behaves like this on the Windows command line, and I spend an hour searching for an encoding error when I remember it's just Windows being not very good.

Answer (score 0):

There is a mismatch between the character encoding of your XML and what you are outputting from PHP. Most likely, one is UTF-8 and one is ISO-8859.

On the PHP side, you can set this with a header directive

```
<?php
header('Content-Type: text/plain; charset=ISO-8859-1');
header('Content-Type: text/plain; charset=utf-8');
?>
```

and/or in the outputted HTML

```
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=ISO-8859-1">
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8">
```

On the XML side, most quality text editors allow you to specify the character encoding as you save the file. (E.g. WordWrangler on Mac)

If the XML file is indeed in ISO-8859, you could use [`utf8_encode()`](https://www.php.net/utf8_encode) to convert it to UTF-8 as you read it in.

[An in-depth discussion of PHP and character encoding](http://www.phpwact.org/php/i18n/charsets).

Comment: Hey I didn't realize that the xml-feed has that on the very first line. I always saw it but I thought it was just a required tag that didn't mean much to us, but rather to an xml-reader software. look at my comment on deceze's answer. Its a bit tougher. <?xml version="1.0" encoding="ISO-8859-1"?>

Comment: Without knowing what libraries you're using it's impossible to say for sure, but I suspect your AJAX call is silently transforming the ISO-8859 into UTF-8. Just use that utf8_encode() function to convert any data that is read from the XML file. (And if you found my answer useful, please consider giving it an upvote.)