# How do you properly decode special characters in XML files?

Tags: php, xml, unicode, character-encoding, libxml2

In some of the XML files I'm parsing (often RSS) I run across text which contains characters like `Today’s Newest` which is becoming `Todayâ€™s Newest` after I extract the text from the node. This tells me I'm handling the decoding process *incorrectly*.

I could simply [patch my script](http://shiflett.org/blog/2005/oct/convert-smart-quotes-with-php) to fix this one bug, but what if there are many other characters that are becoming garbled? What is the proper way to digest XML files without trashing the encoding when converting it to a UTF-8 script?

Here are some of the things I've tried which don't seem to quite work:

```
$xml = file_get_contents($file);

// One: still contains â€™
//$xml = @iconv('UTF-8', 'UTF-8//IGNORE', $xml);

// Two: LibXMLError Entity 'rsquo' not defined
//$xml = htmlentities($xml, null, 'UTF-8');
//$xml = htmlspecialchars_decode($xml, ENT_QUOTES);

// Three: still contains â€™
//$xml = mb_convert_encoding($xml, "UTF-8", "UTF-8");

$xml = simplexml_load_string($xml, null, LIBXML_NOCDATA | LIBXML_NOENT);
```

Comment: Check how you output your content. This could also happen if the output target does not support UTF-8. I assume you output to a browser, so check browser encoding and try explicitly setting it to UTF-8 as you might get correct text from XML but it just displays wrong. Also try loading XML with DOMDocument if above doesn't help.

Comment: See this;-

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9123370/special-characters-from-xml-file-dont-display-correctly-using-php

Comment: @zysoft, that solved the `â€™` problem! Since the XML was getting so large I stopped using the CLI to debug and moved to a browser. I can't believe I forgot to check my headers! `header('Content-Type: text/html; charset="UTF-8"');`

Comment: @Xeoncross, I will post it as an answer. Glad it helped you!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Check how you output your content. 
This could also happen if the output target does not support UTF-8.

I assume you output to a browser, so check browser encoding and try explicitly setting it to UTF-8 as you might get correct text from XML but it just displays wrong.

Also try loading XML with [DOMDocument](http://www.php.net/manual/en/class.domdocument.php) if above doesn't help

Comment: `header('Content-Type: text/html; charset="UTF-8"');`

Answer (score 1):

Give this a try:

`$xml = simplexml_load_string($xml, null, LIBXML_NOCDATA | LIBXML_NOENT);
$xml->addAttribute('encoding', 'UTF-8');`